# How to display something different, if already displayed recently, or previously, in ConTeXt?

Tags: bibliographies, context

I am working on a document that needs to use the Chicago-Turabian style, but last I checked, only APA and one other style were supported by ConTeXt.

I created the following work-in-progress which gets 80% there:

```
\defineregister[turabiancitations][pagenumber=no, indicator=no, before=, n=1]


\def\definecitation{\turabiancitations}

\define[2]\turabian{%

    %% defines first footnote
    \footnote{%
        \cite[author][#1], %
        {\it \cite[title][#1]},
        (\cite[address][#1]: %
        \cite[publisher][#1], %
        \cite[year][#1])%
        \setbox0=\hbox{#2\unskip}%
        \ifdim\wd0=0pt
            .%
        \else
            , #2.%
        \fi
    }%
    
    %% define bibliographical entry
    \definecitation{%
        \cite[author][#1].
        {\it \cite[title][#1]}.
        \cite[address][#1]: %
        \cite[publisher][#1], %
        \cite[year][#1].    
    }%

}%

\starttext
    \turabian{apple2019}{33}
    \placeregister[turabiancitations]
\stoptext
```

Within Turabian style, there are two simple rules for the display of the footnoted items:

1. If the footnote has been displayed once before in the document, display a short version (author + title + page number only) of the citation in the footnote.
2. If the footnote was just called (exact same bib_key called twice or more in a row), then just show ibid. + page number only in the footnote.

How can I get ConTeXt to check if that bib_key has been previously called, to show the short version of the citation, and to further check if that same bib_key was just called right before, to instead show ibid.?

Comment: Usual way to do this is to use something like `\setvalue{turabian::#1}{\relax}` in the definition of `\turabian`. And then, a check like `\ifcsname turabian::#1 \endcsname` can be used to check if had been used before.